# What does array<int,2> dim mean in this piece of code?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates, copy-constructor

I came across this piece of code while reading The c++ Programming Language 4th edition

```
template<class T>
class Matrix {
    array<int,2> dim; // two dimensions

    T∗ elem; // pointer to dim[0]*dim[1] elements of type T

public:
    Matrix(int d1, int d2) :dim{d1,d2}, elem{new T[d1∗d2]} {} // error handling omitted

    int size() const { return dim[0]∗dim[1]; }

    Matrix(const Matrix&); // copy constructor

    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix&); // copy assignment

    Matrix(Matrix&&); // move constructor

    Matrix& operator=(Matrix&&); // move assignment

    ˜Matrix() { delete[] elem; }
    // ...
};
```

There are two data members in the class of which one is a pointer of type `T`. I am not able to understand what `array< int, 2 >` `dim` means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is making use of the std::array from the standard library. You can find a detailed reference here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

`array<int,N> x;`

declares an array of integers of length N; N is 2 in your case.

This is later used to store the shape of your matrix.

Answer (score 4):

The member variable `dim` stores the size of the first and second dimension of your 2D matrix, `Matrix< T >`. Those two sizes are stored as an `array< int, 2 >` (I assume [`std::array< int, 2 >`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array): an array of two values of type `int`).

Without this member variable `dim`, `Matrix< T >` has no idea how many elements are contained in its heap-allocated array `elem` (**note** that `elem` is a pointer to the first element contained in the array of contiguous elements). So `Matrix< T >` has no way of safely iterating these elements, since it would not know when to stop. (In fact the only useful operation `Matrix< T >` can perform, is deallocating the heap-allocated array, as is the case in your destructor.) Therefore, the size of the heap-allocated array (i.e. `dim[0] * dim[1]`) is explicitly stored as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's a declaration of member variable `dim` of type `array<int, 2>` (probably `std::array`.)